# How to pull from a git source and push to another

Tags: git, go

I am using golang (go get) to fetch code from github.com (various repos) into a local repo

`c:\gopath\src\...`

However, afterwards I am unable to push these to local bit bucket server.

BUT, If I download zips from git hub and extract and then i can push to local source code repo.

Am I doing it wrong and what should otherwise be doing ?

thank you

Comment: Add an other git remote.

Comment: Are you trying to push multiple libraries to a single bitbucket repository?

Comment: Yes, trying to club dependencies together

Comment: In that case, you need a git-aware package manager instead. See reference to glide in answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add a git remote for each repository that you've pulled.

> $ git remote add **bitbucket** https://mybitbucketserver.example.com/bitbucket/projects/repo.git

And when you need to push to bitbucket, you say:

```
$ git push bitbucket master
```

Ref: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/

**Edit: Consolidating Dependencies**

You might also consider including a git-aware package manager like [glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide/blob/master/README.md) into your build workflow.